# Start service in Android

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I want to call a service when a certain activity starts. So, here's the Service class:

```
public class UpdaterServiceManager extends Service {

    private final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_EX = 1;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    public UpdaterServiceManager() {}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Code to execute when the service is first created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int icon = android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sync;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
        CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
                contentIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_EX, notification);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Started!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Check if there are updates here and notify if true
            }
        }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void stopService() {
        if (timer != null) timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

And here is how I call it:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setAction("cidadaos.cidade.data.UpdaterServiceManager");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

The problem is that nothing happens. The above code block is called at the end of the activity's `onCreate`. I already debugged and no exception is thrown.

Any idea?

Comment: Careful with Timers - AFAIK when your service is shut down to free resources this timer will not be restarted when service is restarted. You're right ```START_STICKY``` will restart the service, but then only onCreate is called and the timer var will not be re-initialized. You can play with ```START_REDELIVER_INTENT```, the Alarm service or the API 21 Job Scheduler to fix this.

Comment: In case you have forgotten, ensure you have registered the service in the android manifest using `<service android:name="your.package.name.here.ServiceClass" />` within the application tag.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Probably you don't have the service in your manifest, or it does not have an `<intent-filter>` that matches your action. Examining LogCat (via `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse) should turn up some warnings that may help.

More likely, you should start the service via:

```
startService(new Intent(this, UpdaterServiceManager.class));
```

Comment: How you can debugg ? never called my service, my debugg not show nothing

Comment: Add a shitton of Log.e tags everywhere: Before you launch the service, the result of the service intent, inside the service class where it would travel(onCreate, onDestroy, any and all methods).

Comment: it's work for my apps on android sdk 26+ but dose not  on android sdk 25 or lower. there have any solution ?

Comment: @MahidulIslam: I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you can provide a [mcve] explaining your problem and symptoms in greater detail.

Comment: @CommonsWare i already asked a question and that's :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49232627/android-apps-crash-when-excute-startservice-on-sdk-25-and-lower

Answer (score 88):

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

Just writing this line was not sufficient for me. Service still did not work. Everything had worked only after registering service at manifest

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    ...

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:label="My Service" >
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: Best example to learn everything regarding services in Android http://coderzpassion.com/implement-service-android/ and sorry for being late

Comment: My search for automation ended here. Used Manifest as well as startService in my App and it works like a charm. Thank you!!

Answer (score 56):

Java code for **start** **service**:

Start service from **Activity**:

```
startService(new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyService.class));
```

Start service from **Fragment**:

```
getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), MyService.class));
```

**MyService.java**:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private static String TAG = "MyService";
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;
    private final int runTime = 5000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");

        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                handler.postDelayed(runnable, runTime);
            }
        };
        handler.post(runnable);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
    }

}
```

Define this Service into Project's Manifest File:

Add below tag in **Manifest** file:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.my.packagename.MyService" />
```

**Done**

Comment: How much does it improve performance when I leave activities and services in the same package? Never heard that before.

Comment: Perhaps they meant performance in a very vague loose sense, not about run speed?

Answer (score 4):

I like to make it more dynamic

```
Class<?> serviceMonitor = MyService.class; 


private void startMyService() { context.startService(new Intent(context, serviceMonitor)); }
private void stopMyService()  { context.stopService(new Intent(context, serviceMonitor));  }
```

do not forget the Manifest

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService.class" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,YourActivity.class);

startService(serviceIntent);
```

add service in manifist

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="YourActivity.class" />
```

for running  service on oreo and greater devices  use  for ground service and show notification to user

or  use geofencing  service  for  location update in background 
reference 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play-services