# how to call a service method from a non-Activity class in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service

I saw this sample on how to bind a service and call its methods from an Activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

But I want to bind a service and call its methods from a non-Activity class.

how can I do this?

as i don't have implementation of the following methods:

`bindService, unbindService`

Comment: you only need a context to bind to a service. the context can be an activity, a service, or an application.

Comment: i don't have implementation of the following methods:

bindService, unbindService

Comment: bindService is a method of Context. you need a context to use bindService

Comment: I understand. What is the adivsed workaround? creating a dummy context member? getting the application's context?

Comment: Your class needs to extend `android.content.ContextWrapper` class, in which `bindService`, `unbindService` and `startService` methods are implemented, and then can use them from your extending class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the same way like from `Activity` just take/pass instance of `content` Activity

Lets say you have `MyActivity` class
and `OtherClass` class

so you run in `OtherClass`

```
 public class OtherClass {

    Context mContext;

    public void init(Context context){
      mContext = context;
    }
    ...

mContext.startService(new Intent(mContext, SomeService.class));
```

**[EDIT]**

In your case:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LocalService.class);
bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

See documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Comment: i don't have implementation of the following methods:

bindService, unbindService

Comment: I don't like to use those methods but its the same concept

Comment: but i took it from android development official site. Then how else

Comment: you can find a lot of info about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765517/start-service-in-android

Comment: but i don't want to start the service. I want to bind a running one.

Comment: again: `bindService` you mentions can be resolved if my class doesn't inherits from Context? Do I really need to manipulate the mContext member?