# Android calling class into background

Tags: java, android

I really had many codes in my class and it calls `Main`.
But I want that class running in the background.

**My way:**
I created another class and extend `Service`. Then, I use `onStartCommand` calling my class which called `Main` and has many codes!

error: ....Service cannot be a cast to a android.app.Activity

I have really no idea!! Somebody help!

Comment: Any simple or advice are really help me!

Comment: [check this may be help this if not then paste ur code here ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765517/start-service-in-android

Comment: Thanks!But I want Service to call another class.Not class calling service.

Comment: ok then user  then Read about messange class in android by which u can send message to another class and u can do any thing
u can call class form messager handler :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging this can help u :)

Comment: This program can get byte from a device, but I need it getting byte in the background. At that time, the user can do anything else on his cellphone.

Comment: Bluetooth program needs to extends ActionBarActivity, but the program which running in the background needs to extend Service.When I Extend two classes, the codes from Bluetooth program which extend ActionBarActivity needs to be inside a public class! Help!!

Comment: why u need to create new object of Actionbaractivity  create both class  seprate and action baractivity  implements from  service call backs and  by whcih why  u can get call from service and u can do
see answer 5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586031/calling-activity-class-method-from-service-class