# Can't start locationlistener service in Android

Tags: android, service, locationlistener

I'm trying to implement locationlistener but when I try to start the service nothing happend.

This is what I implemented in the manifestfile:

```
 <service android:name="LocationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="LocationService"
        />
```

I implemented a class Locationservice with the following code:

```
public class LocationService extends Service
{
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "Hello World";
    private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public MyLocationListener listener;
    public Location previousBestLocation = null;

    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    /** Checks whether two providers are the same */
    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }

    public static Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {

                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        return t;
    }
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc)
        {
            Log.i("**************************************", "Location changed");
            if(isBetterLocation(loc, previousBestLocation)) {
                loc.getLatitude();
                loc.getLongitude();
                intent.putExtra("Latitude", loc.getLatitude());
                intent.putExtra("Longitude", loc.getLongitude());
                intent.putExtra("Provider", loc.getProvider());
                sendBroadcast(intent);

                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location changed! Data sended to GCM & you are " + distance + "meters away from geofence",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

And in my Activity class I want to start the service,

```
Intent LocationService = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
this.startService(LocationService);
```

Nothing happend when I change from location, anyone know what i'm missing?

Comment: Have a look at this question, it might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765517/start-service-in-android

Comment: Have you added the required permissions to your manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An intent is a message to the system. Here you want to tell it to start your LocationService class as a service. To do it you need to provide the class of the Service you want to start: `LocationService.class`

```
Intent service = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
this.startService(service);
```