# Start service after setOnUtteranceProgressListener on done?

Tags: android, service, text-to-speech

I have a problem i want to start android service after Text to speech finish speak.

Here is my Code

```
HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
        myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
        t1.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
        t1.speak("I can speak anything",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

---

```
@Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    t1.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                            // Log.d("MainActivity", "TTS finished");
//here i want to start my service
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));// but its not working

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                        }
                    });;
                }
            }
```

Please help me....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem - why can't you just start the service where you want to using the standard method? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12555333/1256219

Comment: startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous android.speech.tts.utterenceProgressListener,java.lang.Class<PACKAGENAME>'

Comment: You need to use the correct context. See my answer and the link to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the service in the standard way, but [startService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)) requires context and if you are inside your `ProgressListener`, that will be the context.

You'll need to use

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
```

If you are using from an Activity, you can use

```
MyActivity.this.startService(new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyService.class));
```

There are more [examples on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4765517/1256219). You can of course [create an intent and add extras to it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8610880/1256219), before using it in this way.

Comment: startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
Your answer is correct mate...... Thanks

Comment: @umair Glad it helped.